# Android : Inserting Handler and thread in service operations

Tags: java, android

I have a service which runs in background in my application. NOw what i want is when my service invokes a progress dialog should appear when background operations are performed.My Code:

> ```
>  public class WService extends
>         Service implements Runnable {
>           private  String TAG_SPV=
>         "SPV>service>WService";    private
>         ProgressDialog pd;    
>           NotificationFactory nf;     Parse
>         parse;    DAOSymbol dao;  WSClient
>         responseClient;   List<Quote> quotes;
>           Map<String, Symbol> symbols;
>               private boolean on;
>
>           public IBinder onBind(Intent
>         intent) {
>                       return null;    }
>
>           @Override   public void onCreate() {
>               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>               super.onCreate();
>               Log.i(TAG_SPV,"responseTojsonArray");
>               parse = new Parse();        dao = new
>         DAOSymbol();      quotes = new
>         ArrayList<Quote>();       symbols = new
>         HashMap<String, Symbol>();
>
>
>                         startService(new Intent(this,
>                       br.com.ops.service.NotificationFactory.class));
>
>
>
>
>                         pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,
>         "Downloading..", "Please wait",
>         true,
>                                false);
>
>                       Thread thread = new Thread(this);       thread.start();     }
>
>           @Override   public void
>         onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
>         {         on = true;
>               super.onStart(intent, startId);
>               Log.i(TAG_SPV,"onStart");   }   
>           private Handler handler = new
>         Handler() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
>                         pd.dismiss();
>
>
>                 } };
>
>
>           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
>           public void run() {
>               Log.i(TAG_SPV,"run");       if (on) {
>                   dao.open(getBaseContext());
>                    //Perform some DB operations as well as hit web service
>
>                   dao.close();
>                   handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
>               }   } }
> ```

I'm getting the following error:

> 06-18 01:12:16.793:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737): Uncaught
>   handler: thread main exiting due to
>   uncaught exception 06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   create service
>   br.com.ops.service.WarnningService:
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
>   Unable to add window -- token null is
>   not for an application 06-18
>   01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2790)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:119)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1917)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) 06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737): Caused by:
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
>   Unable to add window -- token null is
>   not for an application 06-18
>   01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:472)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   br.com.ops.service.WarnningService.onCreate(WarnningService.java:56)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2780)
>   06-18 01:12:16.823:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(737):     ... 10
>   more

Please help me .. I'm not sure about the role of handler in this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a progress box while you perform a long-running task, use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Google has a great into to these [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 0):

Services do not get to use the UI. Create an activity for the UI, or establish a Notification instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast comment . Can you please tell me how to use notification because i cant perform operations in activity..need to use service..